# How to run docker image produced by VS 2017

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

Docker noob here...

How does one properly run the docker image of your Asp.Net CORE app which is produced by Visual Studio 2017 at the command line?

```
docker run -it -d -p 80:32769 myappimage
```

does not appear to work properly (image runs, but I cannot browse to my app)

Note: I've simply created a sample ASP.Net Core Web App within Studio using the default template, and added Docker support (by clicking the "Add Docker support" checkbox.).  Studio adds a dockerfile and some docker-compose files when you do this.

When Visual Studio "runs" the image (by pressing F5) - I can successfully browse to my application ( via "http://localhost:32789" or similar host port.  App inside container is on port 80 ).  But I cannot figure out the command to run it myself at the command line.

The standard Dockerfile that Studio adds to your project is...

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:1.1
ARG source
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication2.dll"]
```

Comment: Probably going to need to give us some more info. Dockerfile, what it's trying to do, what 'cannot browse to app' means, etc...

Comment: What is your docker host?

Comment: Is your App configured to run on port 80? Default port is 5000 when you use the ASP.NET Core template

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Rebuild your solution in the **Release** configuration and try to run the `docker-compose` project with `F5` to ensure the image is updated and your app is working fine. Then execute `docker images` [console command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/). You'll see something like:

```
REPOSITORY   TAG      IMAGE ID       CREATED              SIZE
Your.App     latest   673b79a6bb3d   About a minute ago   294 MB
```

All you need is to run a new container from that image and map its exposed port to a localhost port. By default, the exposed port is `80` (look at `Dockerfile`). For example:

```
docker run -d -p 1234:80 --name some_name Your.App:latest
```

Then your app should become accessible at `http://127.0.0.1:1234/`.

Explanation:

If the **Debug** configuration is set, then **empty** non-workable images are created by Visual Studio. It manually maps the empty container to the filesystem to make possible debugging, "Edit and Continue" features and so on. This is why `dev` image is useless without Visual Studio. Build the image in the **Release** configuration to make it usable.

The full publishing process is described in the documentation: [Visual Studio Tools for Docker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/docker/visual-studio-tools-for-docker)

> Publishing Docker images
>
> Once you have completed the develop and debug cycle of your
>   application, the Visual Studio Tools for Docker will help you create
>   the production image of your application. Change the debug dropdown to
>   **Release** and build the application. The tooling will produce the image
>   with the `:latest` tag which you can push to your private registry or
>   Docker Hub.

Comment: Thanks very much i was looking for this answer for days

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing here something. When you run your project with F5 in Visual Studio 2017, you run it with IISExpress on a randomly configured port.

In Docker you don't have IISExpress, there your app is only hosted by Kestrel (Kestrel is always used even behind IIS/IISExpress, but they act as reverse proxy).

The default port for Kestrel is 5000, but you can also configure it. See my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40552670/455493) for more detail on which methods you have to configure the listening ip/port.

Comment: @Franciscod'Anconia: Please take the time to properly read the answer, it **doesn't claim** anywhere that IISExpress runs in Docker. The issue is, if you add(ed) docker support (at least at the time of writing iirc) retroactively (vs. adding checkbox when creating the project), it didn't automatically become the F5-starting application, which is evident by the OPs posting of the url using a high port number `32789`. When started in docker, this won't happen, which is a clear indicator that the OP had left the default start/debugging setting, which is IISExpress