# dotnet docker /bin/sh: 1: [dotnet,: not found

Tags: docker, .net-core, dockerfile

I build successfully with dockerfile, but when I try to run a new container from the build image, I get the following error:

What do i have to do for the solution?

> Error : /bin/sh: 1: [dotnet,: not found

#### docker run command:

```
docker run --rm -it -p 8080:80 furkaandogan/myapp:0.1
```

#### Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:1.1
ARG source
WORKDIR /app
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://*:80
EXPOSE 80
COPY ./publish/myapp .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myapp.dll"]
```

Comment: If you have built the image in Visual Studio, this link could help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43720639/5112433

Comment: Please do not edit solutions into the problems -- doing so makes it impossible for the community to review a proposed solution (even the OP's proposed solution) distinct from the problem itself. The appropriate way to share a solution is with the "add an answer" link, as you've done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the docker ignore file does not allow the copy address

I solved the problem by adding the address to the docker ignore file or using the allowed file address

**Old dockerignore config**

```
*
!obj/Docker/publish/*
!obj/Docker/empty/
```

**new dockerignore config**

```
  *
    !obj/Docker/publish/*
    !obj/Docker/empty/
    !publish/myapp
```

Comment: I would be rather surprised if you could reproduce `Error : /bin/sh: 1: [dotnet,: not found` by reverting back to your prior .dockerignore file, but no doubt it was causing issues that would result in a different error.

Comment: this is actually the best answer i've got out there. because im checking my logs on jenkins and the last i've got this error was actually when  i added a gitignore to this project.

Comment: but putting that gitconfig code above, did not change anything from my builds im still getting the same error

Answer (score 6):

I faced similar issue. In my case the problem was in the entry point statement in Dockerfile. I was missing a **comma** between two parameters "dotnet" and "url for dll".

Before:

```
CMD ["dotnet" "url to dll"]
```

After fix applied:

```
CMD ["dotnet", "url for dll"]
```

Comment: irrelevant to the subject, and the matter was dissolved. I have a problem encountered problems associated with permission to build context

Comment: A missing comma, incorrect quote, or any other invalid json would certainly cause the error message in the question.

Comment: I also got this error when using single quotes instead of double quotes in the `ENTRYPOINT` / `CMD` lines.

Comment: I got this error due to that there was comment at the end of statement.

Comment: Changing single quotes to double quotes in ENTRYPOINT worked for me

Answer (score 2):

There is something on your entrypoint line of the Dockerfile to trigger docker into seeing it as invalid json and it's falling back to shell execution of the string instead. It looks correct in what you pasted, so I'd check for characters like smart quotes or perhaps a Windows newline at the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Above answers are quite clear, but I followed above and changed my `CMD [ 'node', 'app.mjs' ]` to `CMD [ "node", "app.mjs" ]`, made sure I added a comma, same thing still happened.

After I mess around for a little while, I started to think, maybe I need to rebuild the docker file again, so I did `docker build .` again. Boom, it works this time!

Such a rookie's mistake! just like when I made changes to Java repo but I don't rebuild the java repo so error still happens.