# /bin/sh: 1: [“npm”,: not found on docker-compose up

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm new to docker and trying to create a container for node apps.

I followed these [tutorial](https://medium.com/statuscode/dockerising-a-node-js-and-mongodb-app-d22047e2806f), but on `docker-compose up` I'm getting always these error:

```
Creating app ... done
Attaching to app
app    | /bin/sh: 1: [“npm”,: not found
app exited with code 127
```

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
COPY package-lock.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install
COPY . /usr/src/app
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

and my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "2"
services:
  app:
    container_name: app
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

Has anyone an idea how to fix this error?

Comment: `“npm”` is not `"npm"`. If you have "smart quotes" in your Dockerfile, it won't parse the string as JSON, so it'll try to run it in the shell -- resulting in the error quoted here.

Comment: Pertinent: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25319631/bash-profile-aliases-command-not-found

Answer (score 23):

You have the wrong quotes in your dockerfile:

```
app    | /bin/sh: 1: [“npm”,: not found
```

doesn't match the quotes in the example you pasted:

```
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Double check your Dockerfile to correct your quotes.

Comment: I'm split on whether to close this as a duplicate of a question with someone using smart quotes vs regular quotes in a slightly different context.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'd be fine marking it as a dup of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44077815/dotnet-docker-bin-sh-1-dotnet-not-found . If you flag it, I'll second it (my vote is binding on the docker tag so don't want to take a unilateral action).

Comment: I had already replaced the brackets, but I had to run `docker-compose up --force-recreate` to apply the changes

Comment: I do not remember anywhere reading that double quotes are needed. I was using `CMD ['npm', 'start']` and getting the same error. This is fixed by changing to double quotes.