# /bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

Tags: docker

```
# cat Dockerfile
FROM golang:1.10
WORKDIR /go/src/app
COPY source .
RUN go install -v
ENTRYPOINT [“app”,”-single=true”,”-port=8080"]

# docker run -p 8080:8080 valkyrie-app:v0.0.1 
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

Getting this error while running docker run but docker build was successfull, can you please suggest on this error?

```
#docker build -t valkyrie-app:v0.0.1 .
.....
Successfully built d9ad881d0278
Successfully tagged valkyrie-app:v0.0.1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [/bin/sh: 1: \[“npm”,: not found on docker-compose up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48192444/bin-sh-1-npm-not-found-on-docker-compose-up)

Answer (score 2):

`“` and `”` are not valid JSON quotes. Only `"` is a legitimate quote, in *either* JSON or POSIX sh.

Thus, your `RUN` command is not valid JSON, so it's being parsed as a shell command (with only one valid double-quote character instead of matched pairs, hence the specific error seen).

If you're on MacOS, see [How to Disable Smart Quotes](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/136402/how-to-disable-smart-quotes) on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: what if you don't have 'smart quotes' because you built the string on the POSIX system itself?  what would throw that error then?

Comment: @WhiteRau, if you have different circumstances, ask a new/different question with a [mre] that lets others see it. The comment above is insufficient information to provide a non-speculative answer.